# Correct use question "a lot of"/"a lot of more"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage

We are currently translating from a German text and one of my coworkers suggested that the translated text should be written like the following sentence:

> "The product has a lot of more features to offer (you)."

While I think it should be written like this:

> "The product has a lot more features to offer (you)."

We are both non-native English speakers, with German as our mothers tongue. So I kindly ask some assistance on how it would be correct for a native speaker.

Comment: You are right: it can only be "The product has a lot more features to offer". The noun phrase "a lot" is a modifier of the determiner "more", and they cannot be separated by an intervening preposition like "of".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A lot more features" is all right but "to offer for you" appears awkward if not incorrect -- I would suggest that you write it as "a lot more features to offer you" or  replace 'a lot' with 'many' and even  drop the 'you' if possible, as in "the product has many more features to offer."

Answer (score 2):

"a lot of" is correct.

"a lot more" is correct.

"a lot of more" is incorrect.